# Optimise multiple inner JOIN

Tags: performance, optimization, mysql-5.7, query-performance

Consider the following query:

```
 mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.id SEPARATOR '\n')
    -> FROM assignment a
    -> INNER JOIN statements s ON a.id = s.assignment_id
    -> INNER JOIN assignment_status_log asl ON a.status_log_id = asl.id
    -> INNER JOIN assignment_status ags ON asl.status_id = ags.id
    -> WHERE ags.category <> 'PASSED'
    -> AND ags.category <> 'TEST'
    -> AND ags.category <> 'REJECTED'
    -> AND ags.category <> 'CANCELED'
    -> AND ags.category <> 'NA'
    -> AND s.id IS NOT NULL
    -> AND s.id IN (SELECT MAX(sts.id) AS dctrn__1 FROM assignment agr INNER JOIN statements sts ON agr.id = sts.assignment_id WHERE agr.id = a.id)
    -> AND s.grade > 0
    -> AND ags.types <> 'CB'
    -> AND ags.types <> 'CD'
    -> AND ags.types <> 'CE'
    -> AND ags.types <> 'CF'
    -> GROUP BY a.id;
```

I would like to have an idea as to how I can troubleshoot what is taking so long.  I have added index on s.grades and ags.types column, and am pondering if I would need to try to have the conditions on the `JOIN` instead of in WHERE clause.  It has currently been running for close to 2 hours, on 500 000 record. Awful.

Any insight or hints as to what is affecting the performance on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements for all tables in your query. Additionally, is it necessary to have all the `<>` comparisons? Is it possible to simplify either `category` or `types` to be just a single `=` comparison?

Comment: 1) `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.id SEPARATOR '\n') ... GROUP BY a.id` is strange... it produces records, where each record contains a lot of the same a.id values separated with linebreaks... do you really need in this? 2) `AND s.id IS NOT NULL` condition is excess - the next condition `AND s.id IN (SELECT ...` guarantees this one is true.

Comment: Try to create indices: a(id,status_log_id), s(assignment_id,id,grade), asl(id,status_id), ags(id,category.types).

Comment: Comparison "not equal" can't be speeded up by indexes and always require the full table scan. The more `<>` comparison you have used the slower query become.